# Get mixed fractions in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
x=$1
y=$2
m=$x
if [ $y -lt $m ]
then
  m=$y
fi
while [ $m -ne 0 ]
do
  a=`expr $x % $m`
  b=`expr $y % $m`
  if [ $a -eq 0 -a $b -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo $m
    break
  fi
  m=`expr $m - 1`
done
z=`expr $x / $m`
w=`expr $y / $m`
echo "$z / $w"
```

I have done for two number taking as taking numerator and denominator for a fraction from user.

But how to reuse this to get Again take numerator and denominator from user. In this case if numerator is less than denominator then print smallest possible integer
numerator and denominator for same fraction. However if numerator
is bigger than denominator then print mixed fractions where fraction
part again should have smallest possible integer numerator and denominator.

For example if user enters 44, 10 then output should be 4, 2, 5 as 44/10=4 2/5

Comment: You need to know the oldest algorithm of them all, the greatest common denominator or GCD, first recorded by Euclid several thousand years ago (c. 300 BCE).  You also need a loop — though I see on review you've got one hidden away in your unindented code (please indent!). Create a function?  And you need to use the Bash native arithmetic `((…))` or `$((…))`, the latter being POSIX-compliant and the former not, but they're remarkably similar in many ways.  Using `expr` is almost always a mistake — especially if you're using Bash — unless there's a compelling portability issue to deal with.

Comment: see [bash-gcd-of-two-nubers](http://www.bashguru.com/2009/08/gcd-of-two-nubers.html)